# Solving Multiple Phase Angles for Multiple Equations

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization, signal-processing, octave

I have several equations and each have their own individual frequencies and amplitudes. I would like to sum the equations together and adjust the individual phases, `phase1`, `phase2`, and `phase3` to keep the total amplitude value of `eq_total` under a specific value like $0.8$. I know I can normalize the signal, but for my purposes I need to have this controlled by changing/finding the values for just the phases in `phase1`, `phase2`, and `phase3` that will do this.

```
Example:
eq1=0.2*cos(2pi*t*3+phase1)+vertical_offset1
eq2=0.7*cos(2pi*t*9+phase2)+vertical_offset2
eq3=0.8*cos(2pi*t*5+phase3)+vertical_offset3

eq_total=eq1+eq2+eq3
```

Is there a way to solve for the three phases so that the amplitude of the summed signals in `eq_total` never goes over $0.8$ by just adjusting/finding the values of the phases?
Here's a picture of a geogebra applet I tested this idea with.
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/c60uqc9dqe4e00l/amp_phase_pic.png?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c60uqc9dqe4e00l/amp_phase_pic.png)

Here's the geogebra ggb file I used to edit/test idea with. (I used this to see if my idea would work) Java is required if you want to dynamically interact with the applet
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4mvi6r7yuehp4m/sin_find_phases_example.ggb?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4mvi6r7yuehp4m/sin_find_phases_example.ggb)

I'm using matlab/octave
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something which can be solved using Brute Force method in MATLAB.

Create a 3D grid for the phases.
Evaluate the sum of the function at each point on the grid.
Create a mask on the grid for the values which satisfy your needs.

Keep those values as a LUT Table.

Comment: Do you have an example? I know about the meshgrid command but how do you make a 3d grid for phases and a mask on the grid?

Comment: Actually you need 4d Grid as you have $ t $ as well. Are you looking phases which for any $ t $?

Comment: yes, t could be 0 to 10 seconds or 0 to any seconds